# REST API trading with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can I use MATLAB for trading using `webread`/`webwrite` as the API interconnection?

Example using curl :

```
Key Value
apiKey      vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A
secretKey   NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j

symbol      LTCBTC
side        BUY
type        LIMIT
timeInForce GTC
quantity    1
price       0.1
recvWindow  5000
timestamp   1499827319559
```

The curl command looks like :

```
[linux]$ echo -n "symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"
(stdin)= c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71


(HMAC SHA256)
[linux]$ curl -H "X-MBX-APIKEY: vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A" -X POST 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559&signature=c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71'
```

So my questions are:
How can I make the HMAC SHA256 signature in MATLAB?
How can I realise this using MATLAB with webread/write?

Comment: If those are real keys, you should revoke them immediately

Comment: Impressive answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How can I make the HMAC SHA256 signature in MATLAB?**

Calculating an hash `HMAC` with pure `Matlab` code is a little bit tricky. Fortunately, `Matlab` allows full interoperability with the underlying `Java` framework, and performing this computation with `Java` is very simple:

```
post_data = 'symbol=LTCBTC&side=BUY&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=1&price=0.1&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1499827319559';
post_data_bytes = unicode2native(post_data,'UTF-8');

secret_key = 'NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j';
secret_key_bytes = unicode2native(secret_key,'UTF-8');
secret_key_spec = javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec(secret_key_bytes,'HmacSHA256');

hmac_provider = javax.crypto.Mac.getInstance('HmacSHA256'); 
hmac_provider.init(secret_key_spec);
hmac = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHex(hmac_provider.doFinal(post_data_bytes)).';
```

The result is `c8db56825ae71d6d79447849e617115f4a920fa2acdcab2b053c4b2838bd6b71`, so the signature matches your `curl` result.

**How can I realise this using MATLAB with webread/write?**

Once the signature has been calculated, you have to communicate with the `RESTful API`. As far as I can see, your `curl` is configured as a `POST` request that defines the header `X-MBX-APIKEY`, hence something like this should do the job:

```
url = ['https://api.binance.com/api/v3/order?' post_data '&signature=' hmac];
options = weboptions('HeaderFields',{'X-MBX-APIKEY' api_key},'MediaType','application/x-www-form-urlencoded','RequestMethod','post');
response = webwrite(url,options);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this [link](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50478-tradesman), to the function called crypto.m. It does a similar work but more easier way to perform it.

I use like this, for balances as example:

```
timestamp=webread('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/time');

timestamp=num2str(timestamp.serverTime);
[key,secret]=key_secret('binance');
string=['&timestamp=' timestamp];
Signature = char(crypto(string, secret, 'HmacSHA256'));
url_ext = [ string '&signature=' Signature];
url=['https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account?' url_ext ];


 options = weboptions('HeaderFields',{'X-MBX-APIKEY' key},'ArrayFormat','json');
 balances=webread(url,options)
```

`'MediaType'` by default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and `'RequestMethod'` is automatic depending on using `webread/websave` (`'GET'`) or `webwrite` (`POST`), but default `'ArrayFormat'` is in **.csv** and is need to return a **json object**.

The result is like this:

```
balances = 

  struct with fields:

     makerCommission: 10
     takerCommission: 10
     buyerCommission: 0
    sellerCommission: 0
            canTrade: 1
         canWithdraw: 1
          canDeposit: 1
          updateTime: 1.5180e+12
            balances: [150×1 struct]
```